# Unity Quaternion.LookRotation Not Working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with Unity 5 and making the logic of some NPC characters that will walk through a plane randomly and with animations. When the characters reaches the destination, a new target is generated after 3 seconds. The animator works fine and so does the pathfinding. Now I want the model to face forward the correct direction.

I am having a weird issue were the model does not seem to follow any conventional relation. First, it works almost fine, since the rotation is almost the one expected. The second path is deviated and after the third one is almost backwards. Is like if somehow the model were calculating the rotation related to something I have no clue.

This is part of the code I am using:

```
Vector3 look = targetPosition - transform.position;     
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(look.normalized,Vector3.up);
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(newRotation);
```

I have also tried setting the transform Euler angles, and this code:

```
float turnAngle = Mathf.Atan2( look.z, look.x ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
float smoothAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle( transform.eulerAngles.y, -turnAngle, rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime );
rb.MoveRotation( Quaternion.Euler( 0, smoothAngle, transform.eulerAngles.z ));
```

Always the same result. Am I missing something? I have read about the root motion in the animator but I have disabled animations and the patter persists. Also, the model seems to have the correct Z direction set. Its driving me nuts!!

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i want to say that you should be using `Quaternion.Slerp` for rotation interpolations. `Lerp` is a more linear interpolation wheras `Slerp` will make rotations seem more natural. Although i do not believe this to be the issue here.

I don't ever really use `Quaternion` functions, so to me your code looks fine. I can however suggest to maybe try an approach using `Vector3.RotateTowards` or even `transform.Rotate`, they should be able to get you what you are trying to accomplish here.

EDIT: I just noticed you are using `rigidBody.MoveRotation` after your custom `Lerp` interpolation. Unity API states:

> Use Rigidbody.MoveRotation to rotate a Rigidbody, complying with the
>   Rigidbody's interpolation setting.

So, `RigidBody` already has its own interpolation it will try to do against your custom interpolation. The issue may lie there, because you are not setting the rotation explicitly. Try just inserting your target direction into `MoveRotation` and rigidbody will try and get you there. It is not an immediate rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your look vector is not near zero length. If you feel a root animation overwrites your rotation use simple cubes instead of NPC characters. To debug your look direction use targetRotation instead of newRotation. You can render debug lines to visualize the line NPC to target. Good luck.

I have not enough reputation points to write this as comment.